# CakePHP ACL database creation without shell access

Tags: sql, cakephp, acl

This may be a really simple question, but I'm trying to create the database for ACL in CakePHP.  I don't have shell access, so I want to simply upload the sql file through PHPmyAdmin.

The cakePHP instruction manual says to use app/config/sql/db_acl.sql, but the most recent download of cakePHP does not have that file.  Instead it has app/config/schema/db_acl.php, which obviously can't be uploaded to create the tables.

Is the sql file still available?  Is there another way to create those tables without hand typing it all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file should be available if you created the project folder using `bake`.
If it's not, it should be in `/cake/console/templates/skel/config/schema/db_acl.sql`.

Comment: Yup...that's perfect.  I didn't bake it, but the file was accessible in that folder.  Thanks!

Comment: Side note: you should not be developing on a server but instead on your local machine. Then you will not have this problem